# Doctrine ORM увеличивает AUTO_INCREMENT при ошибке MySQL #1062

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Создаю сущность в доктрине орм, конфигурация ID такая

```
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
private int $id;
```

, у сущности есть уникальные ключи

```
#[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING, unique: true)]
private string $username;

#[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING, unique: true)]
private string $email;
```

Проблема в том, что если попытаться в транзакции добавить вторую запись с одним и тем же email или username, несмотря на то, что INSERT не выполнится и будет отловлено исключение
`"An exception occurred while executing a query: Duplicate entry 'username' for key 'users.username'"` и сделано `$conn->rollBack()`

, AUTO_INCREMENT возрастет. И при следующем добавлении (если до этого удачный INSERT вернул ID = 1) он (ID) будет не 2, а 3.

Как правильно реализовать правильное увеличение и/ или формирование AI?

UPD: + добавил prePersist

```
public function checkExistingRecords(array $fields, LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $obj = $args->getObject();
        $repository = $args->getObjectManager()->getRepository($obj::class)->findOneBy($fields);
        if($repository instanceof $obj) {
            throw new EntityAlreadyExistsException($obj::class);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно кому надо, вот ответ (решение)

```
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
#[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: IdGenerator::class)]
private int|null $id = null;
```

```
<?php

namespace CLB\Database;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;

class IdGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{
    
    public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        $table = $em->getClassMetadata($entity::class)->getTableName();
        $maxId = $em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('MAX(id)')
            ->from($table)
            ->executeQuery()
            ->fetchOne();
        return is_null($maxId) ? 1 : $maxId + 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: У меня есть сильное подозрение, что если создавать две сущности одновременно, то с таким кодом они рискуют получить одинаковый id

Comment: Да, есть такое. А какой выход есть?